Error when compiling libaom-sys when targeting aarch64-linux-android
I'm writing an Android application using rust and I need to open avif files. So I use the crate avif-decode which itself uses libaom-sys crate.
When I target windows (x86_64-pc-windows-msvc), I can build the app and open avif file, but when I try to target aarch64-linux-android to build an Android app, I get this log:
error: failed to run custom build command for `libaom-sys v0.15.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\dev\rust\slint_test\mobile\target\debug\build\libaom-sys-5f32384c0bb8129f\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = None
  running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\user\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\libaom-sys-0.15.0\\vendor" "-DENABLE_DOCS=0" "-DENABLE_EXAMPLES=0" "-DENABLE_TESTDATA=0" "-DENABLE_TESTS=0" "-DENABLE_TOOLS=0" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib" "-DAOM_TARGET_CPU=aarch64" "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=aarch64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\dev\\rust\\slint_test\\mobile\\target\\aarch64-linux-android\\debug\\build\\libaom-sys-3f28be3ff867c54f\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android23" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android23" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android23" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

  --- stderr
  CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/Platform/Android-Determine.cmake:217 (message):
    Android: Neither the NDK or a standalone toolchain was found.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:212 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:28 (project)


  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (project):
    Failed to run MSBuild command:

      C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      Version MSBuild 17.9.8+b34f75857 pour .NET Framework
      La génération a démarré 22/04/2024 09:48:06.

      Projet "C:\dev\rust\slint_test\mobile\target\aarch64-linux-android\debug\build\libaom-sys-3f28be3ff867c54f\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-msvc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" 
sur le noud 1 (cibles par défaut).
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(839,5): error : The BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project 'VCTargetsPath.vcxproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x64'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\dev\rust\slint_test\mobile\target\aarch64-linux-android\debug\build\libaom-sys-3f28be3ff867c54f\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-msvc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
      Génération du projet "C:\dev\rust\slint_test\mobile\target\aarch64-linux-android\debug\build\libaom-sys-3f28be3ff867c54f\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-msvc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" terminée (cibles par défaut) -- ÉCHEC.

      ÉCHEC de la build.

      "C:\dev\rust\slint_test\mobile\target\aarch64-linux-android\debug\build\libaom-sys-3f28be3ff867c54f\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-msvc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (cible 
par défaut) (1) ->
      (_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform cible) ->
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(839,5): error : The BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project 'VCTargetsPath.vcxproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x64'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\dev\rust\slint_test\mobile\target\aarch64-linux-android\debug\build\libaom-sys-3f28be3ff867c54f\out\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-msvc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

          0 Avertissement(s)
          1 Erreur(s)

      Temps écoulé 00:00:00.26


    Exit code: 1



  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\cmake-0.1.50\src\lib.rs:1098:5:

  command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

  build script failed, must exit now
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

If I open the VCTargetsPath.vcxproj I'm able to build it (after installation of C++ mobile development package).
I also see Android: Neither the NDK or a standalone toolchain was found. But NDK 26.3 is installed and NDK_HOME correctly set (I'm able to build and run the android app if I remove the dependency to libaom-sys). So rustup target is correctly installed, and android NDK and SDK too.
I've also installed MSVC v143 - Build tools ARM64/ARM64EC VS 2022 C++ (last version) (but during installation I've only seen Desktop in sub-packages names, no mobile or android, so I guess I can uninstall it).
I've also tested to add:
[target.aarch64-linux-android]
linker = "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.3.11579264/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android30-clang.cmd"

to my Cargo.toml but I get the same result. Nevertheless, on posts where I saw this suggestion there was also a ar=aarch64-linux-android30-ar but I haven't any "ar" files on my system.
To summary, I'm able to build on windows with avif support, on android but without avif support.
So I guess I shouldn't be so far to be able to build on android with avif support.
EDIT
To add some details, here is the (very simple) build.rs used by cargo:
fn main() {
    slint_build::compile("ui/appwindow.slint").unwrap();
}

(and appwindow.slint contains only slint code relative to the ui).
Moreover, if I set environment variable CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.3.11579264\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
I get:
error: failed to run custom build command for `libaom-sys v0.15.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\dev\rust\slint_test\mobile\target\debug\build\libaom-sys-5f32384c0bb8129f\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = Some("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.3.11579264\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake")
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_aarch64-linux-android = None
  CMAKE_aarch64_linux_android = None
  TARGET_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = None
  running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\user\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\libaom-sys-0.15.0\\vendor" "-DENABLE_DOCS=0" "-DENABLE_EXAMPLES=0" "-DENABLE_TESTDATA=0" "-DENABLE_TESTS=0" "-DENABLE_TOOLS=0" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib" "-DAOM_TARGET_CPU=aarch64" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.3.11579264\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\dev\\rust\\slint_test\\mobile\\target\\aarch64-linux-android\\debug\\build\\libaom-sys-3f28be3ff867c54f\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android23" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android23" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android23" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"
  -- ANDROID_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version
  21.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
...


Have you tried specifying the CMake toolchain file that comes with your NDK as CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE?

No. If i do so, I indeed see the path to this file in the log and the error change :
-- ANDROID_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version   21.  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

If you scroll down a bit to "Usage" you can click "command line". You need to set ANDROID_PLATFORM and ANDROID_ABI too...

It should be already defined in the Cargo.toml:
[package.metadata.android.sdk]
min_sdk_version = 23
target_sdk_version = 30
If we need to set/change environment variable each time it's not very easy. How can I set these values in Cargo.toml or any config file dedicated to this project ?

I think those versions are metadata for the APK this build will eventually generate. The actual SDK version and ABI used for the native bits must be fixed in advance. What does your outer build system look like?

I've edited the post to easily give you more information.
